# Run plumber API on multiple ports

Tags: r, plumber

I was wondering of there is a way to run a plumber API on multiple ports
I tried this

```
r <- plumb("my_ws.R")
r$run(host = "0.0.0.0" , port = c(9595, 8585))
```

but I didn't work

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.rplumber.io/reference/pr_run.html) seems to indicate that the port argument only takes a singular number or integer, so it seems unlikely.  You could always open multiple R sessions and serve the same API on different ports.